# Find coordinates of beginning and end of a street

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Suppose I know the coordinates of the intersection of 4 streets: A, B, C, and D. If I know that a car Z is 100 meters away from the intersection on street A, is there a service that will let me derive car Z's coordinates?

This is straightforward to calculate if the street setup is a complete grid - but this is infrequently the case.

Answer (score 0):

Google won't do this for you.  You'll need to grab the segments of street A starting from the intersection, then add up the distance of each segment starting at the intersection until you exceed 100 meters.  Then interpolate on the last segment to find the location of Z.

Comment: What service will get the segments for me?

Comment: @Mike You'll need to use a data source such as openstreetmaps to get individual road segments.  See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67302/how-to-get-a-city-road-network-as-line-segments

Comment: When you query a route from google it will give you segments along that route (in order to draw the blue line overlay), so you might be able to tease some of that information out of google, but I don't believe you're supposed to be grabbing or using that data, and creating a route that includes the segment(s) you're interested in sounds like a non-trivial exercise.  But it might be easier than incorporating your own data source.  However the problem you're trying to solve leads me to believe you might, in the long run, be better off using a real data source anyway rather than other services.